# python-telegram-bot - process the output of a ReplyKeyboardMarkup

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm using `python-telegram-bot` and I need to process the output of a reply keyboard to use this in further steps (e.g., to return to the user an output based on her choice).

This is my code

```
def start(update, context):
    reply_keyboard = [['Boy', 'Girl', 'Other']]

    update.message.reply_text(
        'Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you. '
        'Send /cancel to stop talking to me.\n\n'
        'Are you a boy or a girl?',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True))
```

How can I use user's choice to return data based on it? The code above just print the choice to the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you're referring to the example `conversationbot.py` from `python-telegram-bot`'s GitHub.

When user selects a choice from ReplyKeyboard, it'll be sent as a message to bot. So you've to pickup that message. For this you've to use `ConversationHandler` where you can define stages/states for a conversation.

Look at the same example you're referring to. The entry point to ConversationHandler here is /start command. Then the bot replies with the keyboard. The next stage here is `GENDER` (you can see `return GENDER` in start function). Here `MessageHandler` is used with `regex` and the callback function is `gender()`. When user selects from the choice, the bot matches the reply with `^(Boy|Girl|Other)$` and this calls `gender()` function if it's true. Similarly the further states in `ConversationHandler` will proceed.

Finally, `ConversationHandler` will end when it reaches the last state or when `/cancel` (fallback) is sent.